# How to get pretty fonts in Google docs on Linux?

Tags: fonts, google

On Mac and Windows the Google docs fonts look all pretty, but when I look at the very same document on Linux (Ubuntu 13.10 and Lubuntu 14.04 at least) the font doesn't look nearly as good.

How do I fix this?

Some screenshots illustrating my point:

[image: Google docs on Mac] This is the prettiness I get on Mac (MacOS X 10.9)...

[image: Google docs on Lubuntu 14.04] ...But on Ubuntu (Lubuntu 14.04) it looks all ugly.

Comment: Do you mind providing a screenshot? Thank you!

Comment: actually two screenshots of linux and windows to see the difference. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The is that the fonts are not installed on your system. You need to have the font .ttf files to have the fonts. I solved this my navigating to my Windows  partition, finding the fonts directory, and copying over the required fonts - Try looking in `C:/Windows/Fonts`

You might also need to install [Ubuntu restricted Extra [image: a]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/).

Also, I previously found [this](http://www.cufonfonts.com/downloadFont/12048/calibri.zip) if you want any Calibri fonts [image]

---

<sub>This is intended to be helpful, but I don't intend to muck around with Windows copyright in anyway....</sub>

Comment: I installed the font, and it seems to have worked, but the font doesn't look the same as on windows. It seems more pixelated and not as clean as it is on windows. I should probably get a screen shot to illustrate this, but not able to right now.

I'm going to try using different fonts and see which have the best compatibility on both systems. It's not a huge deal, but it would be nice for it to look like it is supposed to.

Comment: If you are editing it, it can look like that - But if often looks exactly the same as the in Windows when printing, or giving it as Presentation *(for Libreoffice Impress, for instance)*. I think you can install some fonts with `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, but that might not work in the latest versions of Ubuntu. The best font for compatibilty is probably Arial :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to install the Microsoft True Type Core Fonts for the Web (available in the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package). These are not installed on Ubuntu by default since they're not open source, but you can add them with:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

After installation, just restart your browser to benefit from the new fonts. :)

Screenshot:

[image: Google docs on Ubuntu after installing extra fonts] Google docs lookin' all pretty on Ubuntu (Lubuntu 14.04).